# error finding .html files for Declarative design

Tags: java, maven, polymer, vaadin, pom.xml

I'm attempting to test out using the declarative design facet to create a root view using the Polymer paper-drawer-panel and assigning the 'main' and 'drawer' elements in the html file.

```
<v-csslayout>
    <paper-drawer-panel>
    <div drawer>

    </div>
    <div main>
        <v-horizontal-split-view></v-horizontal-split-view>
    </div>

  </paper-drawer-panel>
</v-csslayout>
```

However, the class I've set to load the html is unable to find the file.

```
Design.read(this)
```

looks for the html file of the same class name in the same package and directory.  Trouble is even if I leave that file in the same location as the class, it looks like Maven strips it out.

Adding `<resources>` includes in to the pom.xml

```xml
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.html</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

just breaks the javascript, meaning I get the runtime error abbreviated below.

```
Widgetset.nocache.js] not found from filesystem
```

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to integrate the paper-drawer-panel into my web app so if there is another method I'd gladly take that if this is too hacky.

Comment: I usually keep them separated from the java classes by creating them under resources, using the same package layout as the classes and without having anything custom configured in the pom for publishing

Comment: The only time I've been able to get the Design.read() to work is when the .html was manually added into the same directory as the class attempting to load it in the 'classes' dir, otherwise I would like to keep these separate under VAADIN/layouts possibly.  Looking at the source code from Vaadin, it uses Class.getResourceAsStream which looks for a local path and I'm not entirely certain what the path would be at runtime (my first webapp).

Comment: Did you try to put them in the` resources` directory, in a package with the same name as the class which reads them? In a maven project the `resources` dir gets published in `<APP_ROOT>/WEB-INF/classes` which is where the classloader looks for the html files most likely, while `VAADIN/layouts` will end up in `<APP_ROOT>/VAADIN`